# Streaming Web Application - Twitter, Facebook, NoSQL or SQL?

Tags: javascript, web-services, streaming, nosql

So we have a design challenge, we have an absolutely clean slate to develop a system which presents the processing results of various social networking feeds like Twitter & Facebook on the web and via an API service like REST. The processing part has already been completed however we now need somewhere to store the results.

The result format looks something like a message ID, the date of the message, the processed timestamp and then a collection of various processing scores. There will be around 200 million messages in this database. So the first thing we need is something to store this data. We are thinking a NoSQL document database might be interesting to try given that we need to be able to select over a range of dates which discounts column family style databases (as I believe key range scanning in HBase is slow). Or the better option may be to simply store this data in good old MySQL or VoltDB. Does anyone have example use cases or stories on their implementation of such a system?

The next thing will be to develop a web application. We need a charting service which can take data in real-time and update the interface. We are thinking of using HighCharts for this purpose. Is there anything better?

Finally we need some sort of API service which can act like a commet application and stream data, something like Twitter's streaming API. I was thinking the best option for this would be node.js.

So I guess the question is are the technologies we have selected the best for the job, are there any good example use cases out there and is there anything anyone would recommend?

Cheers!

Comment: It looks like you have done your homework and just need additional validation. I think you have chosen a sensible technologies to start with. My only comment is only related to the storage. One of our projects use MongoDB for large analysis transaction because we originally thought that it is better suited for us. During the performance testing however, we are finding out that while it is nice from interface point of view, it doesn't really scale to where we want so we switch back to good old relational DB. Definitely doesn't apply to all NoSQL implementation, but something to think about.

Comment: Thanks for the info Momo. I think more and more that maybe a Col Fam store is the way to go. The only thing I'm not sure of is the query performance, I guess I need a way to generate sequentially increasing keys and just dump records in HBase. The issue is if I want to do a lookup by date I would need to develop an index table that says like for Date/Time have x columns with IDs X have the results. So the question is what is a scan return rate for say keys > X vs doing a similar thing on an Indexed Table in MySQL. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About storage: There are 4 types of nosql storage. key/value, column database, document database and graph database. Each one is slower than the previous one but also gives you more features. In case you need only to store data key/value or column database is your choice. With this type of storage data processing is done by hand and you may need some kind of map reduce implementation. Maybe hadoop. Document and graph databases gives you some kind of query and you can move part of data processing in database (e.g. date filters). If i have to choose some nosql storage I'll make tests with graph database (e.g. neo4j) and If i have performance issues switch to column database (e.g. cassandra) and map reduce

About charts: HighCharts seems good option. I don't know about svg browser support and if there are some performance issues but On my machine looks very nice.

About data streaming. I have little experience only with nodejs and it will be my first choise. There are few other implementations like Tornadoweb for python and Misultin, Mochiweb and Cowboy for erlang. I found a link with [benchmark](http://www.ostinelli.net/a-comparison-between-misultin-mochiweb-cowboy-nodejs-and-tornadoweb/) of this servers and it seems erlang servers are faster than nodejs. You can also look at them.

Comment: Thank you very much for that info! I guess the biggest problem is getting data out in a historical fashion (e.g. the user wants to view a graph of the last weeks results) but also have it so we can stream data in real-time so as new processed records are added to the DB they can be sent to the web interface. With HighCharts it looks like that needs to be done using polling, but thats ok. The question is what is the fastest polling method. I.e. in something like HBase asking for a timestamp key > date or a ID field > last ID or running an SQL query in say MySQL for ID > xyz or timestamp > abc??

Comment: If you have updates every second pooling is better choice. In other case push is better option as far as you won't do dummy requests. I guess highcharts can be adapted to use memory store and fetch data from array filled by nodejs or some other server.
Also twitter will open source Storm in (I hope) few weeks. It seems useful but I haven't tested it as it's still closed. Anyway you can check this post for some preview: http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/08/storm-is-coming-more-details-and-plans.html

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting like on Storm. Been looking at S4 but Storm may be more 'production ready' on release. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SOLR/Lucene with sharding. Throughput can be increased by having a master/slave solr setup.